# try and catch javascript unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

i'm tryin to identify the error i get in a javascrip function in my webpage, so i added

```
function guardarMisDatos() throws Exception {
try{
...
} catch (Exception e){
alert("error: ", e);
}
```

but when i open the page, the chrome web console gives me error at

```
function guardarMisDatos() throws Exception {
```

and the error type is "Uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected identifier"
where is the error? is it a correct way to check way the function is not fired on the first click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove "throws Exception" and the catch reference to "Exception". To know what kind of exception it is, look at the e.name property, it'll be one of six things:

- EvalError - An error in the eval() function has occurred.
- RangeError - ut of range number value has occurred.
- ReferenceError - An illegal reference has occurred.
- SyntaxError - A syntax error within code inside the eval() function has occurred. All other syntax errors are not caught by try/catch/finally, and will trigger the default browser error message associated with the error. To catch actual syntax errors, you may use the onerror event.
- TypeError - An error in the expected variable type has occurred.
- URIError - An error when encoding or decoding the URI has occurred (ie: when calling encodeURI()).

These aren't constants, they're the actual string, as in `if (e.name.toString()=="TypeError")` There are a lot of other good things on the error object too, read more at http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch2.shtml

Comment: this answer is ok, but still i can't get to know the error i'm getting . i posted the real question here, if you want to help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531486/encodeuricomponent-fails-the-first-time-need-two-clicks-to-work

Answer (score 5):

It is JavaScript not Java. Lose the `throws Exception`!

Comment: Remove `Exception` from inside your catch brackets!

Comment: i still don't get error, but i know that the fuction is not firing. look i posted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531486/encodeuricomponent-fails-the-first-time-need-two-clicks-to-work

Comment: There is already an answer to that question and your feedback there is also horrible. I will not continue helping you. Read the FAQ of SO carefully!

Comment: i know, but that doesn't solve my problem, that's why i was searching for a way to detect WHY that happens, so if someone could help would be great (i'm not an expert)

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks a lot like Java, not javaScript. The syntax for try/catch in javaScript goes like this:

```
try {
    // do stuff
} catch (e) {
    // something bad happened
}
```

Notice there is no `throws` and no type on `e` (since javascript is loosely typed)

Comment: i still don't get error, but i know that the fuction is not firing. look i posted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531486/encodeuricomponent-fails-the-first-time-need-two-clicks-to-work

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `throws Exception` from your function definition. You do not need this in JavaScript. Besides that, why would your function ever throw an exception - you already catch it!

Comment: ok but how can i know what kind of error is it there? i deleted throws exception, but now i get the same error at the end where there is "catch {...}"